# How to get/set WI field value in custom control TFS 2017

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, plugins

I wrote a control for the work item using [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/ui-controls/comboo) manual. With the help of tfs Power Tools I changed the xml markup and output my control to WI. As a result, each work item has in itself my control. How can i get/set values of the fields (Found in, AssignedTo, State, etc.) of the current work item in my control (using js)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make REST calls to the TFS API using [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/restclient/workitemtrackinghttpclient2_2) service.

Getting values could look like this (TypeScript):

```
public getWorkItemValues(): Q.Promise<any> {
    return Q(WIT_Services.WorkItemFormService.getService()).then((service) => {
        return service.getFieldValues([fieldRefName1, fieldRefName2]);
    }).then((values) => {
        // do something with the values
        // values[fieldRefName1]
        // values[fieldRefName2]
    });
}
```

Setting is similar:

```
public setWorkItemValues(value1: string, value2: string): Q.Promise<IDictionaryStringTo<boolean>> {
    return Q(WIT_Services.WorkItemFormService.getService()).then((service) => {
        const fields: IDictionaryStringTo<string> = {};
        fields[fieldRefName1] = value1;
        fields[fieldRefName2] = value2;
        return service.setFieldValues(fields);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
`VSS.require("TFS/WorkItemTracking/Services"], function(WIService) {
 WIService.WorkItemFormService.getService().then(
    function (service) {
        service.getFieldValue(this._fieldName).then(
            function (value) {
                // do somth
        });
        service.setFieldValue(this._fieldName, value).then(
            function (result) {
                //do smth
        }); 
    });
});`
```